# Can Adobe AIR app communicate with iPhone calendar

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, flash, air

Hey all,
I'm mighty new to Adobe AIR and Flex, Flash etc

I've been looking through the Adobe AIR APIs, and could not find a class that will allow a Flex\Flash app to communicate to the calendar, 
(more specifically, the iPhone calendar via the iPhone packager)

am i missing out something here?
or has adobe not implemented an API for the Flex apps to communicate to the calendar?

Are there other iPhone specific APIs that Adobe has not implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the iPhone Calendar exposed via APIs?  I would have assumed it wasn't, as it is just another application.  That said, I'm sure there are plenty iPhone specific APIs not exposed yet; as Adobe abandoned development on the iPhone packager when Apple changed their developer agreements.  They resumed development after Apple changed the agreement again, but the iPhone Packager has not gone through a major update yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found the answer right here:
http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Applications_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ#Which_native_iOS_APIs_and_functionality_are_supported_when_using_Flash_tooling.3F

it also shads light on some of the discussions that had taken place in the comments here
for instance:

1. one can develop in Flex, and deploy using the iPhone Packager, but Adobe discourage that at this point
2. exactly what APIs are exposed via AIR

Thanks all for your comments

Answer (score 0):

Since the only thing out right now is a Flash (not Flex/Air) to iOS packager (that I am aware of), you shouldn't expect any specific iPhone APIs to be exposed.  Even Adobe suggests that the packager shouldn't be used for Flex apps yet.

That being said, Adobe has hinted strongly at a Flex to iOS packager.  At that point, I would expect many of the Air SDK features that are meant to abstract the hardware to interface the calendar.  The mobile SDK already has "Native App Integration" support for Email, Browser, Maps, Phone and SMS.  Though I have not seen Calendar, I would expecte it in a fully baked mobile OS abstraction like Air.

Until we get all the pieces, we have to wait patiently, I think.

Comment: There is a command line compiler piece of Flash's iPhone packager which can be used against Flex SWCs.  In theory you should be fine if you use Flash Hero mobile components to generate your SWF and the command line compiler to turn it into an iOS app. See http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/ and http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/09/packager-for-iphone-refresher.html for more details.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: Sure.  I am familiar with that tool.  The only problem is that Adobe has said that it is only technically possible and that they are working on something for Flex in the future: http://bit.ly/exwYdE.  In addition, the second link you gave shows many people trying to convert a Flex Hello World without any success.  It is all 4.1, (not Hero) but still... I haven't seen any evidence that anyone has had any success getting a simple Flex Hero app converted.  I would love to see an example of this, because I want to be able to do it myself... (continued)

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: Finally, there is the mobile SDK to consider.  All of the phone features (GPS, sensors, calendar integration, etc) require the Mobile Air runtime for an abstraction layer to get to the features exposed in the OS. In order for Adobe to make a packager for that, they need to create a similar abstraction in libraries for the packager. Since the only public packager is for Flash, not Air, I highly doubt they will have converted those OS hooks necessary to abstract the phone features to the Flex developer.  At least, that is my take on it. Honestly, I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not letting me edit my comment. here it is: The "Something" they are working with for Flex in the future is the Hero mobile component set, which I called out in my comment.  These components are available in the prerelease builds of Hero.  The iPhone packager does use Adobe AIR; don't mistake the runtime (Flash/AIR) for the IDE (Flash Pro). Last I heard it uses AIR 2.1 and has not been updated for AIR 2.5 yet.  I haven't heard of anyone having success (or not) deploying Flex Apps to iPhone. But, I'm not surprised there are issues as beta software is often a moving target.