# Adobe AIR Flex builder 4.5 for mobile communicate with native calendar on iOS and Android?

Tags: mobile, calendar, air

I've seen this post [Can Adobe AIR app communicate with iPhone calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483220/can-adobe-air-app-communicate-with-iphone-calendar)

But it is out of date, and things have changed since then.

Does anyone know if this is possible short of a [hack](http://workflowflash.com/45648/hacking-native-android-with-air-app-to-allow-air-access-unavailable-apis.php)?

My research hasn't been promising, as it looks to be impossible at this point in time. Anyone found otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIR 3 which is coming out soon, will allow us to do communicate with native code.